# Paste Together Consecutive Non-Digit Elements

Tags: r, regex, text, replace, stringr

## Question

After identifying elements in a character vector that satisfies a non-digit pattern, how can I paste together those elements that consecutively satisfy the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) pattern?

## Overview

`sample_text` mostly contains two patterns:

- odd elements: contain 6-digits followed by text;
- even elements: contain 4-digits followed by text.

However, there are a few instances of non-digit text that belong to the odd element that precedes it.

### Previous Solution

Previously, I was unaware of consecutive non-digit elements in the character vector. This allowed me to manually paste each non-digit element to the element which was directly two elements behind the non-digit element.

```
# load necessary package
library(tidyverse) --------

# load necessary data ------
sample_text <-
  c("811411 Home and Garden Equipment Repair and"   
    , "7699 Repair Services, Nec"
    , "Maintenance" # non-digit pattern
    , "811412 Appliance Repair and Maintenance"       
    , "7623 Refrigeration Service and Repair"         
    , "811412 Appliance Repair and Maintenance"       
    , "7629 Electrical Repair Shops")

# previous solution -------
sample_text %>%
  # for those elements which satisfy the non-digit pattern
  # identify the index of those elements which are exactly two behind
  replace(list = str_detect(., "^\\D*$") %>% which() - 2
          # of those elements which are exactly two behind the non-digit pattern
          # paste the non-digit pattern to the end of them.
          , values = paste(.[str_detect(., "^\\D*$") %>% which() - 2]
                           , str_subset(., "^\\D*$"))) %>%
  # only keep elements with digits
  str_subset("\\d")

# [1] "811411 Home and Garden Equipment Repair and Maintenance" # successfully copied the non-digit element and pasted it two elements behind
# [2] "7699 Repair Services, Nec"                             
# [3] "811412 Appliance Repair and Maintenance"                
# [4] "7623 Refrigeration Service and Repair"                  
# [5] "811412 Appliance Repair and Maintenance"                
# [6] "7629 Electrical Repair Shops" 

# end of script #
```

### Current Problem

Now that I realize `sample_text` contains consecutive non-digit elements, I am unsure how to update my previous solution. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
# sample data -----
sample_text <-
  c("811310 Commercial and Industrial Machinery and"
    , "7692 Welding Repair"                           
    , "Equipment (except Automotive and" # non-digit pattern (1/2)           
    , "Electronic) Repair and Maintenance" # non-digit pattern (2/2)         
    , "811310 Commercial and Industrial Machinery and"
    , "7694 Armature Rewinding Shops"                 
    , "Equipment (except Automotive and" # non-digit pattern (1/2)           
    , "Electronic) Repair and Maintenance" # non-digit pattern (2/2)    
    , "811310 Commercial and Industrial Machinery and"
    , "7699 Repair Services, Nec"                     
    , "Equipment (except Automotive and" # non-digit pattern (1/2)         
    , "Electronic) Repair and Maintenance" # non-digit pattern (2/2)        
    , "811411 Home and Garden Equipment Repair and"   
    , "7699 Repair Services, Nec"                     
    , "Maintenance" # non-digit pattern (1/1)                               
    , "811412 Appliance Repair and Maintenance"       
    , "7623 Refrigeration Service and Repair"         
    , "811412 Appliance Repair and Maintenance"       
    , "7629 Electrical Repair Shops"                  
    , "811412 Appliance Repair and Maintenance"       
    , "7699 Repair Services, Nec")

# desired output ------
 [1] "811310 Commercial and Industrial Machinery and Equipment (except Automotive and Electronic) Repair and Maintenance"
 [2] "7692 Welding Repair"           
 [3] "811310 Commercial and Industrial Machinery and Equipment (except Automotive and Electronic) Repair and Maintenance"
 [4] "7694 Armature Rewinding Shops"           
 [5] "811310 Commercial and Industrial Machinery and Equipment (except Automotive and Electronic) Repair and Maintenance"
 [6] "7699 Repair Services, Nec"           
 [7] "811411 Home and Garden Equipment Repair and Maintenance"   
 [8] "7699 Repair Services, Nec"                       
 [9] "811412 Appliance Repair and Maintenance"       
[10] "7623 Refrigeration Service and Repair"         
[11] "811412 Appliance Repair and Maintenance"       
[12] "7629 Electrical Repair Shops"                  
[13] "811412 Appliance Repair and Maintenance"       
[14] "7699 Repair Services, Nec"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from your expected output, you iterate over the vector and if a line does not contain any digits it should be added to the element before, i.e. current `index - 1:`

```
x <- c()
for(i in sample_text){
  if(grepl("^\\D*$",i, perl=TRUE)) {
    x[length(x)-1] <- paste(x[length(x)-1], i)
  } else {
    x <- c(x, i) #append
  }
}
```

Output:

```
 [1] "811310 Commercial and Industrial Machinery and Equipment (except Automotive and Electronic) Repair and Maintenance"
 [2] "7692 Welding Repair"                                                                                               
 [3] "811310 Commercial and Industrial Machinery and Equipment (except Automotive and Electronic) Repair and Maintenance"
 [4] "7694 Armature Rewinding Shops"                                                                                     
 [5] "811310 Commercial and Industrial Machinery and Equipment (except Automotive and Electronic) Repair and Maintenance"
 [6] "7699 Repair Services, Nec"                                                                                         
 [7] "811411 Home and Garden Equipment Repair and Maintenance"                                                           
 [8] "7699 Repair Services, Nec"                                                                                         
 [9] "811412 Appliance Repair and Maintenance"                                                                           
[10] "7623 Refrigeration Service and Repair"                                                                             
[11] "811412 Appliance Repair and Maintenance"                                                                           
[12] "7629 Electrical Repair Shops"                                                                                      
[13] "811412 Appliance Repair and Maintenance"                                                                           
[14] "7699 Repair Services, Nec"
```

**[Online sample](https://ideone.com/qZxeIN)**

Comment: Thank you! This did exactly what I was looking for, @wp78de. I appreciate you helping me improve my question and for solving my problem.